# Issue with Fake Splash Coming in Android before Custom Splash In React Native App

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, splash-screen

I have created a Custom Splash In My React Native Application & it works well on All iOS Devices & even works on couple of Android devices.

So the issue coming in Android device is when I launch Application by Clicking on App Icon first it shows the Black screen with the App Icon as a Fake Splash & then it shows the custom Splash which.

So is there reason why it's coming only on Specific Android device ?

And is there any way we can disable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after doing lots of research I found the root cause of why this additional splash coming only on specific Android devices just before Custom Splash.

So the reason is In Android OS & later OS versions there is an additional Feature presented called "Default Splash", So What it will do is It will take App Icon as a Logo & will load it in centre of the black screen while launching the Application as a Default Splash.

So you won't need to do any extra efforts for adding a Splash Screen it will automatically take it.

**Important Note :**

As mentioned above it will only work on the Android devices running with OS version 12 or higher. Android OS below 12 devices will work normally without Default Splash screen.

**Possible Solutions :**

Now the important question is how we can deal with it if we want to show our on custom splash. So for that there are couple of possible solutions which we can try out.

**Solution-1 :** We can override the Default splash with custom splash, However its not a tried & tested solution but we can definitely try on it

**Solution-2 :** We can show Custom Splash Just after the Default Splash, This is tried & tested possible scenario & works well on all android devices. Only it will make difference will be like on OS 12+ devices it will show Default as well as Custom Splash & on older devices it will show only Custom Splash

**Solution-3 :** Last possible solution is We can try to disable the Default Splash, how ever this is not recommended solution

Hope this will help to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplest solution for this problem:

Go to `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`
Disable the app's preview as follows:

````xml
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item> // <--- ADD THIS
        // Other items...
    </style>
</resources>```

thanks to this[https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/338#issuecomment-447251703] comment.
````

Comment: Setting android:windowIsTranslucent to true causes all kinds of unwanted side effects, such as crashes when setting the orientation to portrait, and the app being displayed as the desktop when swiping up from the bottom of the screen (i.e. the overview used to browse open apps and hard closing them)